# HTML5 audio: Change the appearance with JavaScript

Tags: html5-audio

In HTML5 is possible to include audio with a simple tag:

```
<audio src="anySong.m4a" controls></audio>​
```

Now I try to change the appearance using JavaScript and JQuery but it doesn't work. Can anyone repair my example or propose another very simple way?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/T47XQ/5/

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/075/Music/35/e5/c6/mzm.pffzpdco.aac.p.m4a">
</audio>

<div id="escolta">escolta</div>
<div id="pausa">pausa</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){

   $("#escolta").click(function() {
     $("#audio").play();
   });

   $("#pausa").click(function() {
     $("#audio").pause();
   });

});
```

CSS:

```
#escolta,#pausa { font-family: Tahoma;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:11px;color: #6666;width: 80px;text-align: center;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;background-color: #ccc;cursor: pointer;}
#escolta {position: absolute;top: 20px;left: 20px}
#pausa {position: absolute;top: 20px;left: 150px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$('id')[0]` to get the raw element (http://jsfiddle.net/T47XQ/6/)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to include audio in a very simple way for IE and non HTML5 browsers?